# How Can I Write A Multiline Regex Expression In Kotlin?

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have a regex that validates a set of a few rules and I thought it'd be nice to have it documented going from this:

```
private val validPathPattern = "^(?!\\./)(?!.*/\$)(?!.*\\.\\./)[0-9A-Za-z!\\-_*'(). /]+\$".toRegex()
```

To this:

```
val regexPattern = """
    ^                        # Start of the line
    (?!\\./)                 # Negative lookahead to exclude "./"
    (?!.*\\/\$)              # Negative lookahead to exclude "/" at the end
    (?!.*\\.\\./)            # Negative lookahead to exclude occurrences of "../"
    [0-9A-Za-z!\\-_*'(). /]+ # Character set allowing specified characters
    \$                       # End of the line
""".trimIndent()

val regex = regexPattern.toRegex(RegexOption.COMMENTS)
```

However, once I change the regex to this multiline format, it stops working.

I've tried different types of escaping and adding the multiline option like so:

```
.toRegex(setOf(RegexOption.MULTILINE, RegexOption.COMMENTS))
```

But it doesn't seem to be working either so I ended up doing:

```
private val validPathPattern = buildString {
    append("^")                    // Start of the line
    append("(?!\\./)")             // Negative lookahead to exclude "./"
    append("[0-9A-Za-z_*'(). /]+") // Character set allowing specified characters
    append("(?!/\$)")              // Negative lookahead to exclude "/" at the end
    append("\$")                   // End of the line
}.trimIndent().toRegex()
```

But I still think it looks much better the other way. Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You are aware that your last `validPathPattern` is not the same pattern as the first one, aren't you? The first pattern is ``^(?!\./)(?!.*/$)(?!.*\.\./)[0-9A-Za-z!\-_*'(). /]+$`` , and the last one is ``^(?!\./)[0-9A-Za-z_*'(). /]+(?!/$)$``, see [the demo](https://ideone.com/1dWXsV).

Answer (score 1):

You're likely facing problems with escaping. Note that triple-double-quoted strings in Kotlin are not just multiline, they also have no escaping, so `\` is no longer an escape character.

For example, if you want a literal `$`, you need `${'$'}` - using `\$` will be considered literally as a `\` and a `$` at the string level, so your regex will contain a literal `$`.

I would suggest to first convert your current regex to a raw string (without line breaks and comments), and see if it still works. I suggest using the built-in IDE conversion to raw string so the escapes are fixed for you.

---

*Side note: as a general rule of thumb, always use raw strings for non-trivial regexes so you don't have to think about 2 levels of escaping (in the string literal AND in the regex pattern).*

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, yes, it is possible, just using a ***triple-quoted string literal***. However, once you pass the pattern to a regex compiler with a [`RegexOption.COMMENTS` option](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex-option/-c-o-m-m-e-n-t-s.html) specified (or using a `(?x)` in the pattern itself), you must remember about the following things (I will mention those specific to Java regex engine):

- You can add comments by typing a `#` character, and all text to the right of it till the end of the line is considered a comment
- All whitespace chars in the meaningful pattern part - even those inside character classes (this is Java specific) - are considered formatting and are not considered when compiling the final pattern. I.e. `(?x)[a b c]` = `[abc]`. To add a space to a character class, you need to escape it with a backslash
- You must also escape meaningful `#` characters in the pattern (yes, even inside character classes) since a `#` signals a start of a single line comment

See [Free-Spacing Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) for more details about freespacing expressions.

In your regex, you actually *must* escape the space inside the character class.

So, the solution looks like

```kotlin
val validPathPattern = """
    ^                        # Start of the line
    (?!\./)                  # Negative lookahead to exclude "./"
    (?!.*/$)                 # Negative lookahead to exclude "/" at the end
    (?!.*\.\./)              # Negative lookahead to exclude occurrences of "../"
    [0-9A-Za-z!\-_*'().\ /]+ # Character set allowing specified characters
    $                        # End of the line
""".trimIndent()
```

So, if you had `\` in the double-quoted string literal (e.g. `"a\\*b"`)  you need to use just one (`"""a\*b"""`).

Note that you do not need to escape the `/` character in the regex pattern as it is not a special regex metacharacter and it is never used as a regex delimiter in Kotlin since you specify patterns using string literals, not regex literals.